# Using GGPLOT2 to show relationships between factor variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to see relationships between Happiness and a multitude of other variables, for example, AGE or SEX or MARITAL STATUS, using `ggplot()`. I have this data set

https://xdaiisu.github.io/ds202materials/hwlabs/HAPPY.rds

```
library(ggplot2)

HAPPY[HAPPY == "IAP"] <- NA
HAPPY[HAPPY == "DK"] <- NA
HAPPY[HAPPY == "NA"] <- NA
```

I downloaded this data set, and I converted some of the variables to 'factors' using this code, I will just use MARITAL and HAPPY as an example;

```
HAPPY <- HAPPY %>% mutate(MARITAL = factor(MARITAL, 
                                           levels = c("NEVER MARRIED", "MARRIED", "SEPARATED", "DIVORCED", "WIDOWED"))) 
               %>% arrange(desc(MARITAL))

HAPPY <- HAPPY %>% mutate(HAPPY= factor(HAPPY, 
                                        levels = c("NOT TOO HAPPY", "PRETTY HAPPY", "VERY HAPPY"))) 
               %>% arrange(desc(HAPPY))
```

Now I want to use a `ggplot2` graph to show the relationship between MARITAL and Happiness(denoted by the column HAPPY). I am relatively new to `ggplot2`, so I am just trying to figure out ways to use it. Also, if you don't want to do HAPPY VS MARITAL then you can use any variable or column to compare to HAPPY as well that you would like I just keep getting errors.

Thanks!

Comment: This is very open ended. but you might try using the `dplyr` package to group your data and find counts of occurrences of the permutations of Marital and Happy columns. ie
`df %>% group_by(MARITAL, HAPPY) %>% summarise (Count = n())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should get you started.

```
#Loading Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggthemes)
```

```
#reading data
df <- readRDS("HAPPY.rds")
```

```
df<- na.omit(df) #deleting NA's

#converting class of categorical columns from  character to factors 
df[sapply(df, is.character)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df, is.character)],as.factor)
df$AGE<- as.numeric(df$AGE)
```

```
#Grouping through dplyr and plotting through ggplot2
df %>% 
  group_by(HAPPY,SEX) %>%
  summarise(mean_age=mean(AGE))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=HAPPY,y=mean_age,fill=SEX))+
  geom_bar( stat="identity",position = position_dodge())+
  labs(x="Happiness", y="Average Age")+
  theme_gdocs()+
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(mean_age,0)) ), vjust=0,position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  scale_fill_manual( values=c( "deeppink","mediumturquoise"))
```

[output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOv3M.png)

Answer (score 1):

A starting point may be simply to visualize count of observations, e.g.: `ggplot(HAPPY, aes(x = HAPPY, y = MARITAL)) + geom_count()`.

You might also try geom_bin2d: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bin2d.html